# Express image upload and view in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to upload an image and show it in express.
I configured my app to upload in 'public/images'

```
  app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: './public/images' }));
```

The upload goes great but I can't find how to show uploaded images in my jade template. The image path I get from the req.files object is something like 'public/images/imagename.jpg' but the only way I can see images is in a url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/imagename.jpg
```

Is there a way to maybe remove the 'public' parameter from req.files, or are there other solutions?? 
Thanks everyone!

EDIT:

Ok, thanks for that. But my question was about showing images in the jade template. I added this line:

```
app.use('/public/images/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images/'));
```

and now I can reach files in that directory. But I'm not able to show them in my jade template. When I try this (with foto_path === req.files.image.path):

```
img(src= #{material.foto_path})
```

I get this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/undefinedpublic/images/b1ce29f40ac7692ac62637e42f0f9128.jpgundefined
```

What are the 'undefined' for?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that Express configure your public directory a little bit differently than other traditional servers like Apache. I guess that for displaying static assets, your line looks like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

That'll be the only publicly viewable folder in your app. This is why Express find it redundant to add the name of the directory to the url. **The url doesn't reflect your actual folder structure.**

But req.files does show the actual path so that you can manipulate it in your app, or else it'd be unusable elsewhere. My solution would be to directly refer to `src = '/images/imageName.jpg'` in Jade. You'd have to pass the actual image name as parameter. Or, you can just strip the "public" part from req and pass it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. But my question was about showing images in the jade template. See EDIT above.

Comment: Well yeah, req.files must show the "public" part, or else it'd be unusable elsewhere in your app. You can simply refer to the actual url directly in Jade: `src = '/images/imagename.jpg'`. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: The issue is that the file name is coming from an upload form. I need to get the right path from that.

Comment: SOLVED thanks to this tutorial http://www.hacksparrow.com/handle-file-uploads-in-express-node-js.html. Thanks everybody!