# Undefined in front and at the end when passing a link inside a variable on Jade and Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using express and Jade. When i pass variable that contains a link i get undefined in front and at the end of the url. What is this problem and how can i solve it?

The same problem as here :
[Express image upload and view in jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251302/express-image-upload-and-view-in-jade)
but it's not answered there.

Jade code:

```
block content
h1= title
p Your photos
#photos
img(src=#{purl})
p #{photo.title}
```

Rendering code

```
res.render('./user/show', { title: 'photos',photo: photo, purl: purl)});
```

purl is the variable of the link which when i console log just above the render appears as should and the photo.title appears too normally.

UPDATE

It's a JADE problem as with EJS everything works great.... Guess for a small problem i'll have to switch.. If anyone comes up with a solution, you're welcome.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: What code? All the other variables are passed the same way and are usable and the links have undefined in front and at the end. What can i upload as part of the code when i don't have a clue where the problem could be? is it the folder where the photos are saved? when i console log right there where i get the variable i get the appropriate link. Only on jade the problem exists.

Comment: As the other user stated, you need to paste some code. The problem is clearly that you are either not passing your parameters to jade properly, or you are not utilizing them properly within Jade. No one will be able to help you more than this without seeing what you're trying.

Comment: Paste the section of your Jade template which is generating the link in question, and well as the res.render line (assuming you're using Express), and a dump of the object you're passing Jade.

Comment: Done, added all the pieces above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, before `res.render()` add a `console.log(purl);`

You want to rule out that the variable is not undefined before it even reaches the Jade template.

In your jade, your image src does not need `#{}` around the purl variable. Try this:

```
img(src=purl)
```

You only need `#{}` when you are inside a text string and want to refer to javascript varaibles.

If you really wanted to, it could be written as `img(src='#{purl}')`

Your paragraph could also be written as:

```
p= photo.title
```

Where the `=` means the following is interpreted as javascript. No need for `#{}`.

If you wanted to mix text with the photo title using `#{}` works like a charm.

```
p #{photo.title} lorem ipsum
```

Comment: I had added the console.log(purl) right above the render and it gave me the link without problem. I did what you told me and thanks for the advice, but unfortunately the problem remains. The most strange part is that using EJS works perfectly without any changes.

Comment: Surely `purl` is not a reserved word in Jade... Try renaming it to `purl2` just for laughs. Also try `p= JSON.stringify(purl)` - maybe it's something to do with the img tag?!

Comment: It was successful after changing to both your suggestions on the answer... You don't know how much trouble you've saved me... Sorry for the problem but i was really lost in this Jade, Ejs mess... Thanks a lot!!!